# Visibility of ajaxToolkit:TabContainer using css

Tags: c#, css, tabs, visibility

I use `ajaxToolkit:TabContainer` to organize page contents. Some times, I need to hide some tabs based on conditions. The problem is, I would like to read the content of hidden tab using JavaScript. So I can not use C#'s `Tab.Visible = false` because it will not render the tab.

When I use CSS's `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden;`, the tab still there (without tab titles). I guess Ajax tab does not support the css properties. What are the alternatives should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TabContainer1.Tabs[0].Enabled = false;` to hide tab, it will still generate the DOM element for this tab and you can access it using javascript.

Comment: I don't really want the user to view my tab if it is hidden